# How do I fit a linear mixed model in R with autocorrelation, when the effect of time is of no interest?

Tags: r, panel-data, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am attempting to fit a linear mixed model with the lme function using R. My data involve repeated measures, but the effect of time is not of interest to me, so I don't want to include it as a fixed variable. I would prefer to treat each point as a subsample. For a bit of context, I had several experimental units (mesocosms) and measured them weekly for 8 weeks. I do not expect the response to build over time, but I want to account for the fact that there will be some autocorrelation. My current model included mesocosm as a random intercept. If I understand this is similar to using corCompSymm in r, meaning that the data are not correlated by time, but simply that there will be more similarity for measurements from the same mesocosm. It seems like I want to use corCAR1 to start, but I'm not sure how to indicate the form correctly. All examples I have found also include time as a fixed variable. A simplified version of my current model looks like this:

model.lme <- lme(response ~ treatment, random = ~1|mesocosm)

I've been reading about linear mixed models for the past month, but I'm still a beginner. Any help is appreciated.